# Delete Query throwing warning db2

Tags: optimization, db2

I am trying to delete multiple records from view 
The view has Instead of Trigger defined ..
The view has records consolidated from multiple tables.

```
 [db2inst1@testServer001 ~]$ db2 "delete from view_XXYY where alarm_mark_id in (52609,52610)"
```

I get  the following warning

```
 SQL0437W  Performance of this complex query might be sub-optimal.  Reason 
 code: "3".  SQLSTATE=01602

 [db2inst1@testServer001 ~]$ db2 ? SQL0437W


  SQL0437W  Performance of this complex query might be sub-optimal. Reason
  code: "<reason-code>".
```

Explanation:

```
  Query optimization is one of the factors that affect application
  performance. The SQL and XQuery compiler performs several steps to
  produce an access plan that can be executed.
```

how do do it in an Optimal way ?

Comment: Don't you think that you should provide the query/view `view_XXYY` definition and the underlying tables' definitions?

Comment: yeah i was about to edit the Question

Comment: It's also useful to post the statement execution plan.